# Improve Grails App in Heroku compression, gzip, expire tags

Tags: grails, heroku, gzip, assets, gsp

I'm trying to improve the speed performance of my page, I have a couple questions

I'm using Grails 3 on heroku.

Is there any way to make a HTML compression(gzip) the gsp pages?
Can I add Image Expires Tag on the header?

for last, Can we use a .htaccess file on a grails app?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache for compression and expires. Don't create a .htaccess file, but create a [virtualhost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html) with a proxy to your Grails application.

Between Apache and Grails you can also add a HTTP cache server, for example [Varnish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varnish_(software)). If what you are serving is mostly static, then configuration will be quite easy and you would see a dramatic speedup(1000x). If you have a lot of dynamic content and sessions, configuring a cache server can become quite complex.

We run our company website with Apache + Varnish + Grails + PostgreSQL all alone on a EC2 t2.micro instance and its blazing fast!